# Javascript Date formatting issue

Tags: javascript, date

I want to obtain a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format from a  JavaScript `Date` object.

```
new Date('Aug 5 2022').toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

From above line, I'm expecting `2022-08-05` but getting `2022-08-04`

how to solve it?

Comment: `"Aug 5 2022"` is not in a format defined to be parseable by the spec. While it's possible that a certain implementation might recognize and handle this format, it is not guaranteed. See here for info about valid datestring formats including a link to the specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#datestring

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because you try to convert to `toISOString` it automatically convert to UTC, I am confident you are not in UTC area. So to fix this use:

```
new Date('Aug 5 2022 GMT+00').toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

So, convert it to UTC then to `toISOString()`

Comment: FYI: Instead of `GMT+00` you can also just write `UTC`

Comment: Correct, I personally like this more because I know which timezone it is, feel more explicit for me.

Comment: See @jsejcksn's comment to the OP. `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')` does the job without relying on parsing an unsupported format. There are a number of languages that will produce the same result (such as "sv").

Answer (score 0):

Your date gets converted to UTC. One way to fix this would be by adding `UTC` to your argument string.

```
new Date('Aug 5 2022 UTC').toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

> **Date.prototype.toISOString()**
>
> The toISOString() method returns a string
> in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27
> characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or
> ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always
> zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix Z. - [Date.prototype.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

Below are two ways to get the `yyyy-mm-dd` string format that you asked about from a native JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

1. Offsetting the date information according to the [system time UTC offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset):

```js
const date = new Date();
const utcOffsetMs = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1e3 * -1;
const offsetDate = new Date(date.getTime() + utcOffsetMs);
const dateStr = offsetDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);

console.log(dateStr);
```

2. Get the individual date parts and [format them with a leading `0` if necessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```js
function getDateString (date) {
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const dayOfMonth = date.getDate();
  return `${year}-${String(month).padStart(2, '0')}-${String(dayOfMonth).padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

const date = new Date();
const dateStr = getDateString(date);

console.log(dateStr);
```

Comment: Or just `date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')`. ;-)